# Why my Mac is not sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, macos-ventura

Every day when i finish my work i put my Macbook to sleep and close the lid (2019 Mb Pro, MacOS Ventura).

Next day when i wake up, i can check the Macbook is not actually sleeping because it's a bit hot, which indicates there are processes running even with the lid closed.

I searched a bit about this issue, and they say the Whatsapp web / application would prevent the machine to sleep by keeping it awake to receive notifications.

Is there a way to prevent this unwanted behaviour ?

Comment: Have you tried to avoid running things that prevent sleeping? It might work...

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425329/85275 If it's an app preventing sleep, then you'll just have to quit it.